# Github Pages .folder/file isn't accessible when going to site on Chrome

Tags: html, git, github, github-pages

I had to add a `.fol-der/file.txt` file to my github pages repo for verification on a platform.

Problem is, I get a 404 error when I enter `username.github.io/.fol-der/file.txt` in the search bar.

I am not using a site builder like Jekyll, just html files of my own.

Any idea why this could be happening? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-pages%5D+dot+files

Answer (score 2):

I have found a fix.

https://github.community/t/also-serving-hidden-folders-after-publishing-to-github-pages-using-github-actions/18120

Just add a file `.nojekyll` in the root of your site’s publishing source.

I would have commented, but I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: This is a good answer, no need to make it a comment.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub pages will not serve files or folders starting with a `.`. You will need to rename your folder so that it doesn't start with this character, or use a different hosting service.